Which verb is used for the voluntary termination of degree-awarding powers?
Which verb is used in BrE to express that a university voluntarily terminates its degree-awarding powers as a result of discontinuing the field of study to which the degree-awarding powers apply?
I initially considered "revoke", which yields some results when I search for it, but it seems to be used only in cases where the degree-awarding powers are withdrawn by another authority because the university no longer meets the requirements. I have also searched for various forms of "cease", "discontinue", "close", "withdraw", "terminate", etc., without becoming any wiser...
I would be truly grateful if someone could help me here!
Clarification: In my country, if a university discontinues a field of study, they also "discontinue" their degree-awarding powers for that field of study. Whether this "discontinuation" means a complete termination of the powers, so that the university needs to apply again if they decide to restart the field of study, or that they are just "on hold", as it were, depends on why the field of study was discontinued. Each university has to apply for, and be granted the power to award degrees, and they have to do it separately for each field of study.

I would say that it still has degree-awarding powers in that situation, it is just choosing not to use them (by not discontinuing the field of study).  If, in the future, it decided to restart that field of study, it would still be able to award degrees.  And it retains degree awarding powers in other fields.  Choosing not to teach a course is not the same as losing any power.

@JamesK Oh, that's unfortunate... It would've been so much easier if you just did things the same as we do them in my country, so there were corresponding words to use, haha. Oh well; if you did do things the same as us though (where you actually "terminate" your degree-awarding powers), what would you say would be the most reasonable choice of verb?

I still don't really understand.  Could the university choose to restart the field of study at some point in the future?

See my answer below.  If I understand you, the university isn't losing any power. It is just not using a power.

degree-awarding powers is quite ambiguous and not accurate. If you cancel a course, you cancel a course or field of study. Obviously, any degrees associated with that field of study disappear. More context would be useful. The university simply stops offering those courses in that field of study,

We could consider relinquish:
The university relinquishes its degree-awarding powers as a result of discontinuing the field of study.

VERB
If you relinquish something such as power or control, you give it up.
[formal]
He does not intend to relinquish power.


Thank you! I'm just thinking "relinquish" has a pretty strong sense of actually giving up (in the sense 'surrender'), if you see what I mean? But perhaps I'm wrong?

No, because it's wrong to say here: degree-awarding powers.

@Lambie In what way is it wrong to use "degree-awarding powers"? What should I call it instead?

@Helen I would say: credentials to confer or award degrees or some other word. Powers always leads to powers as in power of attorney.

@Lambie Would "degree-awarding credentials" work, or do I have to use the paraphrase "credentials to..."? What about "degree-awarding authority"?

It seems that the university isn't losing or terminating any "power". It still has the power to offer degrees. All that is happening is that it is discontinuing a course, or a field of study.

From 2025, the University of X will close the computer science department and no longer offer degrees in computer science or related subjects.

In Britain, a "University" is a body that has the power to grant degrees, in any subject it wishes. Not every university offers degrees in every field of study, but all have the power to do so. In this way, a "university" differs from a "college", as these organisations can only offer degrees through an association with a university.

I don't think the question is very clear. Do you know what uni is being referred to?  You're saying "the university" as if you did.

Ooohh... Ok, then I get it. In my country each university has to apply for, and be granted the power to award degrees, and they have to do it for each field of study.

@Lambie I guess JamesK just means 'the university that OP is talking about' :)

What you see is that even an apparently simple word like "university" has no exact translation.  Moreover the meaning of "university" has a legal meaning in England, and a legal meaning in New York, and a legal meaning in Scotland (etc) but these countries/states have different laws, so the legal meaning of "university" will be different in England from Scotland...It can be easy to forget that the rules for these institutions differ between jurisdictions.

@JamesK Very true!

Granting the unclarity that  @JamesK mentions about whether the university’s action can later be reversed, I suggest shelves. It’s somewhat informal, but semantically (and based on the obvious metaphor), the verb shelve does allow for the scenario of their eventually resuming the granting of the degrees.
